# What is simplest way join __contains and __in?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I am doing tag search function, user could observe a lot of tags, I get it all in one tuple, and now I would like to find all text which include at least one tag from the list.

Symbolic: `text__contains__in=('asd','dsa')` 

My only idea is do loop e.g.:

```
q = text.objects.all() 

for t in tag_tuple: 
   q.filter(data__contains=t)
```

For example:
input tuple of tags, `('car', 'cat', 'cinema')`
output all messages what contains at least one word from that tuple, so `My cat is in the car` , `cat is not allowed in the cinema`, `i will drive my car to the cinema` 
Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you give an example of some input and expected output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:

```
filter = Q()
for t in tag_tuple: 
   filter = filter | Q(data__contains=t)
return text.objects.filter(filter)
```

A couple of tips:

- You should be naming your model classes with a capital (i.e. `Text`, not `text`)
- You may want `__icontains` instead if you're not worried about the case

Comment: Nice if it will work, looks simple, thx +1 and accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Django, so I have no idea how to apply this filter, but it seems you want a function like this one:

```
def contains_one_of(tags, text):
    text = text.split()   # tags should match complete words, not partial words
    return any(t in text for t in tags)
```